# What is optical wireless communication?

Tags: communication, wireless, optical

What is the term optical wireless communication? According to my point of view, in optical communication there msut be a medium so the refractive index should be capable of keeping the wave inside the medium. Can you explain it?

Comment: think of a flashlight sending morse code

Comment: What if the medium is air?

Comment: Fiber optics + wireless

Comment: You should have a look to technologies such as Lifi

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_optical_communication

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a simple question for a definition that should be Googled.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why optical communication needs to be fibre optic.

Sending Morse code using an Aldis lamp is a form of wireless optical communication.  For computers, IrDA was an early protocol, using infra-red LEDs to communicate between laptop computers and peripherals.  More recently, LiFi has been put forward as a way to communicate around an office space - the computers and routers flicker bright LEDs at a rate too high for the human eye to percieve.